# Powershell foreach to csv

Tags: powershell, csv, snmp

First time trying to use powershell, so I accept that this might be beyond a beginners level.

Objective: Create a CSV from data collected by snmpget.exe (syntax "snmpget.exe -IPAddress -OID"). CSV should be organized by 3 columns that represent 3 different pieces of data collected by snmpget.exe (the 3 OIDs) and rows by IP addresses.

So I've got my list of IPs and I've got my OIDs. I need to run a foreach IP against all 3 OID values in the executable.

```
$AddressList=@("192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3")
$OID1 = ForEach ($Address in AddressList) {snmpget.exe -r:"$Address" -o:1}
$OID2 = ForEach ($Address in AddressList) {snmpget.exe -r:"$Address" -o:2}
$OID3 = ForEach ($Address in AddressList) {snmpget.exe -r:"$Address" -o:3}
```

My first issue was attempting to export just $OID1.

```
$OID1 | Export-CSV
```

Doesn't exactly work because the only string property is length, so I don't actually get the value I want. I then tried Out-File. That works, but I'm not sure how I combine $OID1, $OID2, and $OID3 into a single CSV file with headers.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output?  `Export-Csv` expects a `[PSCustomObject]`

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if you just want to know how to nest loops, you can do something like this:

```
$AddressList = "192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3";
$OIDList = '1','2','3';

$AddressList | ForEach-Object ($Address in $AddressList) {
    $Address = $_;
    $OIDList | ForEach-Object {
        snmpget.exe -r:"$Address" -o:"$_"
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Export.csv
```

However, that's going to be super useless since `snmpget.exe` is not outputting any objects that `Export-Csv` is looking for.  I expect `Export-Csv` to complain that it doesn't have a header.  You could just write out a text file with `Set-Content -Path C:\Export.txt` or `Out-File -FilePath C:\Export.txt` instead of `Export-Csv`, but that's just dumping the output to a text file.

I don't have any SNMP enabled devices on my network, so I have no idea what the output from that `snmpget.exe` command looks like.  Your question is mostly unanswerable without knowing the output of `snmpget.exe`.

You may want to try the `Get-SNMP` command from [this module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NetCmdlets) or something similar from one of [the other SNMP modules](https://www.powershellgallery.com/items?q=snmp&x=0&y=0) in the Gallery.  That will output objects instead of plain strings, which will be easier to manipulate.